# What are the prerequisite subjects related to program installers?

Tags: operating-system, windows-installer, file-management

I never needed to add an installer to my programs but I always wondered about Microsoft Installer (.msi or .exe installers). What tasks do they do?

They make the life easier for the user, but that's not all to it. I know they also deal with the Operating System in several aspects.

But before learning about installers themselves. I feel there's a gap on my knowledge on some prerequisite subjects related to this.

So, which subjects would they be? And where can I learn them? (Books, articles, videos, courses, ...)

And to be clear I'm not asking about how to create an installer (I can do it with Visual Studio or tools like Install Shield). But I'm more concerned about the prerequisite subjects I need to learn to proper understand and handle installers. Specially in what areas do they deal with the Operating System?

Answer (score 0):

Installers are nothing special. They give this impression because they do a bunch of weird things that don't seem accessible to other apps. The .msi and .exe installers will self extract (take a portion of the file itself and copy it to another file) or they will download other files from a server. The .exe and .msi files are thus normal executables that the OS recognizes due to their file extension as files that it should execute.

Each file extension has a default app to open them. When you open a file, its default app is started and the path to that file is passed as a string to the main function of the app. That way, the app can parse the file and show the content of it to you (similarly to compiling a program).

Other things like creating desktop icons are available with some dlls native to Windows and some other libraries that call in those dlls for higher level languages like C#. Quite simply, you create an average window like any other, you extract the app being installed from the same file to Program Files and you're good minus some other minor details. The apps available are really just to make your life easier.